# monitoring muliple machines from one monit webpage

Tags: monit

I have multiple machines, a monit instance running on each of them. I'd like one of the instances to be the "master" instance, i.e. the other machines would report to it and I could monitor them all from the master page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [**M/Monit**](http://www.mmonit.com) (for "multi-Monit")

You establish a connection to the central collector and your existing Monit installations will begin to report to it.

The cost is nominal and this is the right solution for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something - this is not something that monit supports out-of-the-box. This is where M/Monit comes in, albeit not free: https://mmonit.com/shop/